# Parquet files and PySpark: creating linestring column from node references

Tags: python, spatial-join, linestring, points-to-line

I've used [osm-parquetizer](https://github.com/adrianulbona/osm-parquetizer) to convert my pbf files to parquet to parallelise my actions using PySpark and Apache Sedona to query as such. The schemas created by the parquetizer didn't have a geometry/linestring column and I'm trying to create one. Fortunately for nodes, I've created a geom column with `ST_Point` for nodes but struggling to create a linestring column for ways.

Node references for an example way are stored as follows - `[{0, node_1}, {1, node_2}]`

Schema for nodes:

```
 |-- id: long
 |-- version: integer
 |-- timestamp: long
 |-- changeset: long
 |-- uid: integer
 |-- user_sid: string
 |-- tags: array
 |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string
 |-- latitude: double
 |-- longitude: double
```

Schema for ways:

```
 |-- id: long
 |-- version: integer
 |-- timestamp: long
 |-- changeset: long
 |-- uid: integer
 |-- user_sid: string
 |-- tags: array
 |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string
 |-- nodes: array
 |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |-- index: integer
 |    |    |-- nodeId: long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sorted it out, attaching a snippet below. Apache Sedona installation is necessary.

```
ways = ways.withColumn("nodes", col("nodes").getField("nodeId"))
exploded_ways = ways.select(ways.id, ways.version, ways.changeset, ways.uid, ways.user_sid, ways.tags, explode(ways.nodes))
exploded_ways = exploded_ways.withColumnRenamed("col","nodes")

query = """
select exploded_ways.id as way_id, nodes.id as node_id, nodes.latitude, nodes.longitude from exploded_ways join nodes on nodes.id = exploded_ways.nodes;
"""
ways_with_geometry = spark.sql(query)
```

After exploding and querying, the snippet to convert lat/lon columns to linestring is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75590260/20982093).